# Navigation with display:table cell where first and last child is a different width

Tags: html, css, css-tables

I have a 'steps' navigation which uses table / table-cell to ensure each item is the same width and occupies the full menu container.  But because of the way it's designed, I want the contents of the first and last child to line up with the edge of the parent.  Any ideas?  Perhaps I'm approaching it the wrong way...

Easier explained with code:

http://jsfiddle.net/davidpauljunior/u499gyvd/

[image]

**HTML:**

```
<ul>
    <li>
        <span class="title">Item 1</span>
        <span class="fa fa-automobile"></span>
    </li>
    <li>
        <span class="title">Item 1</span>
        <span class="fa fa-automobile"></span>
    </li>
    <li>
        <span class="title">Item 1</span>
        <span class="fa fa-automobile"></span>
    </li>
    <li>
        <span class="title">Item 1</span>
        <span class="fa fa-automobile"></span>
    </li>
</ul>
```

**CSS:**

```
body {
    margin: 0;
}

ul {
    display: table;
    table-layout: fixed;
    width: 100%;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    list-style: none;
}

li {
    display: table-cell;
    width: 100%;
    text-align: center;
    position: relative;
}

li:after {
    content: '';
    display: block;
    width: 100%;
    height: 2px;
    background-color: gray;
    position: relative;
    top: -10px;
}

li:first-child:after {
    width: 50%;
    left: 50%;
}

li:last-child:after {
    width: 50%;
}

.title {
    display: block;
    margin-bottom: 10px;
}

.fa {
    position: relative;
    z-index: 1;
}

.fa:before {
    padding: 4px;
    background: white;
    border: 1px solid gray;
    border-radius: 50%;
}
```

---

EDIT:

What I'm essentially after is the first and last items have `width: auto` (so they are only as wide as they're actual contents) and then the items in between (e.g. 2, 3, 4) to divide the remaining space equally.

Answer (score 0):

remove these 2 styles;

```
li:first-child:after {
    left: 50%;
    width: 50%;
}
li:last-child:after {
    width: 50%;
}
```

They are not needed if you require the first item and last item to be touching the left and right of the ul.

You are then going to need to set the first item to text-align: left; and the right item to text-align: right; (instead of centered aligned as it currently is)

Comment: Those 2 styles make the 'journey bar' start and end at the correct location (I don't want the bar to start before the first circle and finish after the last circle).

Comment: They wont if you align them left and right, they are center aligned what do you expect?

Comment: I was hoping someone may have a solution on a way to achieve this effect.  I understand that `text-align: center` will center the text.  I want the text centered.  But I want the first and last items to effectively be `width: auto` with the remaining items in the middle equally dividing the remaining width.